# How can I alter the font size from a plugin in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I would like to alter the font size from a plugin in IntelliJ IDEA. Let's say I will add a button to double the font-size, as otherwise configured under `Appearance & Behavior > Appearance > Size`.

For this plugin I am using a custom action, as laid out in the [IntelliJ documentation](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/action_system/working_with_custom_actions.html).

Which API can/should I use to alter the IDE's font size?

Answer (score 0):

We can mix & match from `com.intellij.ide.ui.AppearanceConfigurable`, resulting in a minimal example like this to increase the current IDE font size by 1:

```java
UISettings settingsManager = UISettings.getInstance();
UISettingsState settings = settingsManager.getState();

settingsManager.setFontSize(settingsManager.getFontSize() + 1);
if (!settings.getOverrideLafFonts()) {
    settings.setOverrideLafFonts(true);
}

LafManager.getInstance().updateUI();
```